# How to exclude ServiceAccountKey.json when I deploy cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I downloaded ServiceAccountKey.json to make local cloud functions env.
I think  ServiceAccountKey.json should not be public and it should not be in GCP.
So when I deploy cloud functions, how do I exclude it?
Or is that no problem to upload ServiceAccountKey.json using `firebase deploy --only functions`?
Please teach me how to do. Thank you.

Comment: Exclude totally the serviceaccountkey.json from your code base. You don't need it

Comment: Do you mean I should delete it? For some future, I think I shouldn’t delete it.

Comment: You shouldn't, you must! It's a security hole. You can do without!

Comment: What about `.env` file? I use environment variable in production. So I should not exclude it in `firebase.json`,  right?

Comment: yes. And also delete the file from your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the ServiceAccountKey.json file out of the deployment folder. This way, it will never be deployed and you also don't have to add it to the git ignore file. You could also add it to the ignored files in your firebase.json file like so:

```
{
    "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "ignore": [
        "ServiceAccountKey.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Julian. Thank you for the prompt response. I will add it to `firebase.json`.
I have another question. Should I also add .env file and all TypeScript file to `firebase.json`?  Please tell me more. Thank you.

Comment: You should generally add all files you don't want deployed to the ignore section of the firebase.json. However, I don't think it is necessary to add the typescript files. Remember, your files are stored in a secure cloud server. Whilst you are correct in removing the ServiceAccountKey.json file from there, since it contains information which allows admin access to your project not necessary for your cloud functions to function, the typescript files are not as security relevant. Thus, keeping them in the folder should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Julian. Make sense. So generally Is what I should exclude in my folder `.env` and `ServiceAccountKey.json`, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Firebase Function emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator), you wouldn't need to manage service account locally yourself by using [Application Default Credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters). You can initialize Admin SDK like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app"

const admin = initializeApp(); // <-- no params
```

Comment: Hi, Dharmaraj. Awesome. I didn't know about it.  Thank you so much.
I have one question. Why need I `ServiceAccountKey.json`?
I use Firebase emulator. So I don't need to download and use this?  Thank you.

Comment: @ShunTakahashi you generally need service account key in case you want to use Firebase Admin SDK in a non GCP env, may it be your on premises servers or so. If you are deploying to Cloud Functions then you don't  need it. For env vars, you can use [secrets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) instead of a `.env` file.

Comment: Hi, Dharmaraj. Make sense. so do you mean If I use all functions and tools on Firebase and GCP, I don't need `ServiceAccountKey.json`. If I connect Firebase with outside's sever, I need it. Is that right? Thank you.

Comment: @ShunTakahashi that's correct. ADC won't work in on premises or other cloud providers so service accounts or any other auth method would be needed.

Comment: What about .env file? I use environment variable in production. So I should not exclude it in firebase.json, right?

Comment: @ShunTakahashi I've already mentioned that  in my previous comments. You can use [secrets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to add env vars.

Comment: Thank you. I will use secret manager for API keys, but I don't know about just `.env` file should be deployed using `firebase deploy --only functions` the same time. I think it should be. Because to unwrap it `.env` file is necessary.